# QML ListView delegate provider component

Tags: qt, qml

Currently im working on a complex program that parse large nested json into a tree and display it. I created a tree to parse data and a model to query data from tree to display it in QML ListView.

Now i need to create a some kind of delegate provider for this model. Each element in tree have its own delegate with different set of options and different qml items. And there must be an option to load new type of delegates in the runtime.

Is there are nice solution to do that? Some kind of custom C++ Loader component? I need an advise. I already know that it can be done using switch case and qml loader. But this solution is not acceptable for me.

Comment: I've had good luck with this in the past. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html Would this work for  you? I can possibly give you more detailed answer later today.

Comment: Yes, i already looked at qml treeview. But this is not work for me. My model are jusl a list of children. 1-D model. But every child can make it own delegate